# Converting latitude and longitude in a rectangle area in R?

Tags: r, coordinates, transform

I'm really struggling in how can I transform my `lat` and `lon` coordinates of my dataframe in x and y (Euclidean coordinates), where the x-axis should vary between `0` and `10`. Here is my data:

```
library(meteo)
library(tidyverse)

data(stations)
test = stations %>% filter((lon>=110)&
                                   (lon<=154)&
                                   (lat<=-12)&
                                   (lat>=-39)) %>% select(lon, lat, elev_1m)

head(test)
#          lon     lat elev_1m
#10440 126.633 -14.300      24
#10908 126.150 -13.750       8
#11102 130.366 -12.633       4
#11947 130.883 -12.417      31
#7035  131.017 -13.050     105
#7717  131.183 -13.833      50


#Fir the desired results, something like
head(desired_results)
#          lon     lat elev_1m
#10440     0.5       5      24
#10908     1.2     4.5       8
#11102       3     2.7       4
#11947      10     2.9      31
#7035      0.8     0.78     105
#7717        9     3.1      50
```

I already tried to perform several procedures, and I did a search here on the other questions, but none of them solved my problem.

Any tips on how I can do this?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I think you want to do a shift and scale operation.

```
library(meteo)
data(stations)
```

To save bringing in all the "tidyverse" packages (and you shouldn't ever do
`library(tidyverse)` anyway), here's the extraction with `subset`:

```
test = subset(stations, 
   (lon>=110)&(lon<=154)&
   (lat<=-12)&(lat>=-39))[,c("lon","lat","elev_1m")]
```

next, shift `lon` and `lat` so their minimum value is zero:

```
test$lon = test$lon-min(test$lon)
test$lat = test$lat-min(test$lat)
```

Now, to make the longitude span from 0 to 10, it has to be divided by a factor dependent on its maximum:

```
range(test$lon)
## [1]  0.00 40.05
scale10 = max(test$lon)/10
```

See how dividing by 40.05 would make it range from 0 to 1, so the scale factor is 1/10 of that. Now scale lon and lat by that factor:

```
test$lon = test$lon/scale10
test$lat = test$lat/scale10
plot(test$lon, test$lat, asp=1)
```

[image]

and check:

```
range(test$lon)
## [1]  0 10
```

if you also want the latitude scaled to be 1 to 10 then you have to compute a different scale factor for latitude and multiply the latitude by that value instead, but that would squash the map when viewed.

Comment: It's exactly what I need. Works perfectly for me.